# Can i use dojotype and onServerClick at the same time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dojo

I tried using onserverclick while having dojotype in my button.

See this code.

```
<button id="ButtonLogin" runat="server" onServerClick="ButtonLogin_OnClick"   dojotype="dijit.form.Button" jsid="ButtonLogin" style="float: right;
                            padding: 5px 15px 0px 0px;">
                           Login</button>
```

So basically i have a void ButtonLogin_OnClick that will be triggered once the button clicked (alert something).
and also the dojotype will also trigger a javascript (alert Something also).

```
<script runat="server">
 void ButtonLogin_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   //alert
 }
</script>
```

As i test it. Only dojotype succeeded.

Can anyone explain it to me or can we both use at the same time??

Answer (score 2):

You need to wire the onClick of the dojo button to call _doPostback with the appropriate parameters.  _doPostback is emitted by ASP.NET and that is the mechanism used to trigger a postback and execute the server side event.

Answer (score 0):

try to add a **return** into your function.

but if you already can use dojo, you should go with it to prevent such problems especially if you do target multiple browsers.

Comment: sometimes yes. particularly if you use IE

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be directly about dojotype this example may help you. I use the following to call javascript then asp.net on a submit.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" onclientclick="javascript:alert('A');" />
```

You can check if the page is valid before executing the javascript

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" onclientclick="javascript:Page_ClientValidate();if(Page_IsValid){ //Do stuff };" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have both ! Basically, dojo and asp.net try to replace the onClick handler, so you won't see both succeeding.

The best solution is to add your postback logic in the dojo click handler:

```
<button id="ButtonLogin" runat="server" 
dojotype="dijit.form.Button" jsid="ButtonLogin" 
         style="float: right;padding: 5px 15px 0px 0px;">
                       Login
  <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="evt">
    __doPostBack('ButtonLogin','');
  </script>
</button>
```

dd

Comment: tried it but still no luck. im thinking it because they are using different form and cant work at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in syntax, click event is not perform and function is not call instead of 'onServerClick' you can try 'onserverclick'. May be this will solve your problem...

Try this code

```
<button id="ButtonLogin" runat="server" onserverclick="ButtonLogin_OnClick" dojotype="dijit.form.Button" jsid="ButtonLogin" style="float: right;
                            padding: 5px 15px 0px 0px;">Login</button>
```

or else
you can call ButtonLogin_OnClick function on Dojo click event this will fire both event together...